# Whenever i ping my bot it shows the API latency as NaNms

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I ping my discord.js bot it shows the API latency as `NaNms`

This is the output

[image]

This is the code

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Pings the bot!',
    usage: '​',
    execute(message) {
        const pingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('Pong!')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.gifer.com/fyMe.gif')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Latency - ', value: `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`, inline: true },
            { name: 'API Latency', value: `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`, inline: true },
        )
        .setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send(pingEmbed);
    },
};
```

Comment: If you add `console.log(typeof client.ws.ping)` to this function, what does it write to the console?

Comment: It shows `number` - [Image here](https://imgur.com/a/lulD76g)

Comment: `client.ws.ping` is coming back undefined or NaN. Probably the latter, if `typeof client.ws.ping` is returning `number`.

Comment: so what to do now?

Comment: Try this: `${Date.now() - parseInt(message.createdTimestamp, 10)}ms`. I guess createdTimeStamp is a string of some sorts

Comment: See i don't have problem in this one but i have problem in the API Latency which is `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem, the API latency is showing correctly for me, tested on both discord.js v12 and v13.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt pass the `client` as here it's undefined 
Either pass the `client` or use `message.client.ws.ping` 
That's the solution unless the code sample you gave is no full one.

Comment: If `client` was not defined it shouldn't send any response/message back. It would have thrown an error. The OP clearly showed us a screenshot with an embed sent back from the bot. Also if you read the comments under the question, the OP tried `console.log(typeof client.ws.ping)` and it has shown him that it is a `number`. That wouldn't work if `client` was not defined or `undefined` ...

Comment: I used `message.client.ws.ping`

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue too, the problem is that you're adding the `client.ws.ping` part in the embed instead of the command.

The embed wont have:
`client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {}`

which is why it gives out "NaNms"

so instead of a separate embed i just made the embed within the command and it works fine, here (but depending on how different the way you set your bot up, it might not work) :

```
message.channel.send({embeds:[{

        title:'Pong!',
        description:`API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}`
        
        }]
});
```